# Delete elements inside a string from a specific character to another in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, filtering, indexof

I wanted to delete from a string a specific series of elements inside two markers.

I will show you an example for be more clear.

This is my string, and from the first opening square bracket from the first Closure bracket I want to delete the element inside and the brackets too.

```
 var x = 'black , [ element ] , blue , green , [ repeated element ]'
```

And the result should be:

```
var x = 'black , blue , green , [ repeated element ]'
```

I tried this code but I can't find a way for a specific delete.

```
var x = 'black , [ element ] , blue , green , [ repeated element ]' 
x = x.substring(0, x.indexOf('['));
document.write(x);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

for first match only `x.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]\s*,?/, "")`

for all match `x.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]\s*,?/g, "")`

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = 'black , [ element ] , blue , green , [ repeated element ]'; 
    var res = str.replace(/(,\s*\[[^\]]*\])|(\[[^\]]*\]\s*,?)/, "");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
x = x.substring(0,x.indexOf('[')) + x.substring(x.indexOf('] ,') + 3);
```